# Updated Android ADT, now getting errors

Tags: android, adt

I've just updated my android adt to version 17 and now i cant start my android projects. When I try to update it gives me an error:

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 17.0.0 or above.  Current version is 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534.  Please update ADT to the latest version.

I've tried to update again but it shows me this

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.  
Android DDMS will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.  
Android Development Tools will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.  
Android Hierarchy Viewer will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.  
Android Traceview will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.
```

Is there a way to fix this or can i downgrade adt to fix this problem

Comment: I suggest you to reinstall your Eclipse and then ADT for eclipse. Note that you don't have to reinstall android sdk again since you already installed it.. And also you could accept some answers to get your Status Up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get the Newest ADT by going to help, install software, and entering https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

if it doesn't let you, choose from 'available sites'

Answer (score 9):

I had almost the same issue when trying to update the Android ADT tools on my Windows 7 machine. Turned out running Eclipse as Administrator solved the issue for me and I was able to update normally.

Answer (score 2):

1. Moved my Android folder to Root.
2. open the SDK manager outside eclipse by browsing into it.
3. Turn of your virus protection
4. Turn off zonealarm
5. Unistall SDk Tools and SDK platform tools.
6. close out the manager and start up eclipse.
7. (Inside Eclipse)  Help -> Install new Software -> ADD " name =" ADT PLUGIN ", 
   location " https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ " ---> OK
   ----->  Check the developer tools box.
   I believe i had a corrupted install of 20 so eclipse knew it was there but did not know it was incomplete.Hope this saves someone the 3 hours it took me to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all folders/jars under \eclipse\plugins and \eclipse\features. Try installing Android ADT tools again. If you still have same error than search android word under eclipse(installation) folder. Delete all except platform.xml. open platform.xml and search android xml tags and remove all. Try installing again. This solved problem below.

Android DDMS will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.
Android Development Tools will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.
Android Hierarchy Viewer will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.
Android Traceview will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.

Answer (score -1):

The step which i have tried is: **Run the SDK Manager and try to update the ADT.**